# T2A fontshape in verbments listings

Tags: unicode, highlighting, verbments

I'd like to use T2A fontshape inside verbments listings (for comments in source code), but have no luck in this. For the code

```
\begin{pyglist}[language=haskell]
fact n = foldl 1 (*) [1..n] -- так определяет !n профессор информатики
\end{pyglist}
```

result with pdflatex is

[image]

result with xelatex is

[image]

Any suggestions how to get plain T2A text in comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `pdflatex` is used, you need to neutralize the active catcode of characters in with the high bit set:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbments}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xpyg@neutralize}{% make characters in the range 128-255 printable
  \@tempcnta=128
  \loop
    \catcode\@tempcnta=12
    \ifnum\@tempcnta<255
    \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
  \repeat
}

\patchcmd{\pyglist@}
  {\VerbatimEnvironment}
  {\VerbatimEnvironment\begingroup\xpyg@neutralize}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\endpyglist}
  {\input}
  {\endgroup\input}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{pyglist}[language=haskell]
fact n = foldl 1 (*) [1..n] -- так определяет !n профессор информатики
\end{pyglist}
\end{document}
```

The same patch is innocuous when XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX is used, but for these you need a monospaced font that supports Cyrillic, for instance CM Unicode.

Here's a version that runs with all three engines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\newif\ifunicodeengine
\ifxetex\unicodeenginetrue\else\ifluatex\unicodeenginetrue\fi\fi

\ifunicodeengine
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{CMU Serif}
  \setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{CMU Sans Serif}
  \setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
\else
  \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi

\usepackage{verbments}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xpyg@neutralize}{%
  \@tempcnta=128
  \loop
    \catcode\@tempcnta=12
    \ifnum\@tempcnta<255
    \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
  \repeat
}

\patchcmd{\pyglist@}
  {\VerbatimEnvironment}
  {\VerbatimEnvironment\begingroup\xpyg@neutralize}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\endpyglist}
  {\input}
  {\endgroup\input}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{pyglist}[language=haskell]
fact n = foldl 1 (*) [1..n] -- так определяет !n профессор информатики
\end{pyglist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With addition of [russian]Babel it works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

run the document with `xelatex` or `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.85]{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\usepackage{verbments}
\begin{document}

\begin{pyglist}[language=haskell]
fact n = foldl 1 (*) [1..n] -- так определяет !n профессор информатики
\end{pyglist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, I prefer pdflatex, so I stick with @egreg answer, but your approach also does work, thank you!